# java streams executed a method limited number of times

Tags: java, for-loop, lambda, java-stream

I am writing a code in old style as follows :

```
 public List<Long> generateSequenceList(final int count) {
        List<Long> sequenceList = new ArrayList<>(count);
        for (int i =0; i <count; i++) {
            sequenceList.add(functionB());
        }
        return sequenceList;
    }
```

In this method i am calling a function for count  no of times and adding result in list.

I wanted to write it via streams example where in using streams but i am not able to get the appropriate method in streams.

are such cases not supported by streams?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Stream.generate` and `.limit`.

```java
return Stream.generate(() -> functionB()).limit(count).toList();
```

Comment: I often see this written using a method lambda, i.e. `Stream.generate(this::functionB)` (if `functionB` is a nonstatic method) or `Stream.generate(ThisClass::functionB)` (if `functionB` is a static method and `ThisClass` is the name of the class containing it).

Comment: @M.Justin Indeed, the definition of `functionB` wasn't shown so I just used a lambda.